# Code optimization by chosing another datastructure

Tags: java, string, optimization, data-structures, char

I have a piece of code that needs to be optimized.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < alphabetLength; c++) {
     if (alphabet[c] != x.word.charAt(i)) {
        String res = WordList.Contains(x.word.substring(0,i) +
                     alphabet[c] +
                     x.word.substring(i+1));
      if (res != null && WordList.MarkAsUsedIfUnused(res)) {
        WordRec wr = new WordRec(res, x);
        if (IsGoal(res)) return wr;
        q.Put(wr);
      }
    }
  }
```

Words are represented by string. The problem is that the code on line 4-6 creates to many string objects, because strings are immutable.

Which data structure should I change my word representation to, if I want to get faster code ? I have tried to change it to char[], but then I have problem with getting the following code work:

```
x.word.substring(0,i)
```

How to get subarray from a char[] ? And how to concatenate the char and char[] on line 4.6 ?

Is there any other suitable and mutable datastrucure that I can use ? I have thought of stringbuffer but can't find suitable operations on stringbuffers.

This function generates, given a specific word, all the word that differs by one character.
WordRec is just a class with a string representing a word, and a pointer to the "father" of that word.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's `WordList` type and what's `WordRec`? Also, `IsGoal` is a method? If yes, then please use caseCamel properly to name it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce number of objects by using this approach:

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(wordLength);
tmp.append(x.word);
for (int i=...) {
    for (int c=...) {
        if (...) {
           char old = tmp.charAt(i);
           tmp.setCharAt(i, alphabet[c]);
           String res = tmp.toString();
           tmp.setCharAt(i, old);
           ...
        }
    }
}
```